# TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am implementing an LSTM the shape of my train data is (5237162, 99, 1).

I create the model as follows and I encounter the error.

```
TypeError: call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'
```

I tried upgrading Keras to the latest version from github. Did not work.

```
LSTM_model = Sequential()
LSTM_model.add(LSTM(256,input_shape=(final_ip.shape[1],final_ip.shape[2])))
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: You need to extract and provide a [mcve], your question as it stands now is considered off-topic without it. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There's no `input_shape` on `LSTM`: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm

Comment: Please include full code, I cannot reproduce the problem with the given code.

Comment: @Caramiriel Every layer accepts an input shape, this comes from the base class Layer, just try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strange! Running your code runs fine in my notebook.
I noticed that 'input_shape' is not an argument of LSTM layer as displayed [on officially keras](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm)

maybe it is a versioning issue!

my versions: keras  '2.2.4', tensorflow '1.11.0'

To bypass it you can try functional api:

```
from keras.layers import Input
input1 = Input(shape =( final_ip.shape[1],final_ip.shape[2] ) )
x = LSTM(256)(input1)

model = Model(input1,x)
```